# Why was this question locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locking, question

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60568/acm-ieee-software-engineering-code-of-ethics-and-professional) came up on my tag clean up, so I can't retag it. I can see it being closed for Not a Real Question, since it isn't good in it's present state. However, I did want to (like I said) retag it, improve the title, and improve the grammar and formatting of the question. I believe that even closed questions should be well-written and formatted - it just makes the site look better.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall, there was an edit war going on.

Since the question has been closed for almost 5 months, has a distinct "homework" bent, and is not solving a practical problem, I chose to delete it instead of unlocking. Although I'm not married to that decision, so if you had an edit in mind that'd improve it to the point where it could be considered for reopening, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Editing enough for reopening was questionable. I would say 50/50. I don't think that I could have done enough to make it clearly reopenable, so a deletion is probably best.